# Top answers for a tag is returning user details?

Tags: support, api, answers

I am expecting top answers for a particular tag here. But it returns user details.
Is anything wrong here?

Using:
[/2.2/tags/java/top-answerers/all_time?site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/java/top-answerers/all_time?site=stackoverflow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the route used has /top-answer**ers**/.  [The doc page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-answerers-on-tags) states:

> Returns the top 30 answer​***ers*** active in a single tag, of either all-time or the last 30 days.

<sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>
So, that route is returning what it should.

If you really want the top answers for a tag, use [the `/search/excerpts` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search) and set:

1. `sort=votes`
2. `order=desc`
3. `q=is:answer`
4. An appropriate filter (follow the example link, below)

For example, this gets the top 30 answers for the Java tag:

[/2.2/search/excerpts?order=desc&sort=votes&q=is:answer&tagged=java&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#pagesize=30&order=desc&sort=votes&q=is%3Aanswer&tagged=java&filter=!*cCFgu5yS7KyzTl9l3QaUn7rEqe-wO6.6%29evY&site=stackoverflow&run=true)